# Mobile only hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I really hope someone can help, I have hacked together some code that does the following

On page load the nav bar is hidden showing the jumbotron as the first element, when the page is scrolled down by 100px the static nav bar fades in this all works fine and the way I want it to work.

Secondly When the jumbotron has been scrolled >600px away it will fade out, now I only really want this to happen on a mobile device (Hiding the jumbotron once its scrolled off the page) and im not sure if there is an easy way to do this?

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if ($(".navbar").length>0) $(".navbar").hide();

  if ($(".navbar").length>100) $(".jumbotron").hide();

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(y > 200){
      $(".navbar").fadeIn("slow");
    }
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(y > 600){
      $(".jumbotron").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});` is the same as `$(function() {});` and that you only need one to wrap all your code in, not every part of code. So just `$(function() { // all your code here });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just wrap your scroll function in an if statement:

```
if ($(window).width() < maxWidth){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(y > 600){
      $(".jumbotron").fadeOut("slow");
    }
  });
}
```

where `maxWidth` is the width you consider a mobile device to be. Bootstrap uses media queries with predetermined `min-width` breakpoints, so you could consider using the same value.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have changed the maxWidth to 768 but it doesn't seem to work? am I doing something wrong? Again thanks

Comment: Thanks working great the code was missing the () after .width to function correctly, many thanks

Comment: Oops sorry. Glad you figured out my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some classes in bootstrap that hides and shows element like :

```
       <div class="hidden-xs" >hide in mobile</div>
       <div class="hidden-lg" >hide in large windows like laptop</div>
       <div class="show-xs" >Just show in mobile</div>
```

there ar 4 break point in bootstrap : 'lg' 'md' 'sm' 'xs'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I wanted the jumbotron to show on page load but when it is scrolled off screen I would like it to fadeout behind the scene and not reappear (mobile only) due to screen space.